# How can I create multi-language popup messages in SweetAlert2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert2

**Explanation of my code:**
 - *pressing **"test"** button* : you can make five circles show up or disappear.
 - *pressing **"English"** button* : contents are changed to English (except for contents in `SweetAlert2` popup messages).
 - *pressing **"Korean"** button* : contents are changed to Korean (except for contents in `SweetAlert2` popup messages).

Inspired by [Adam Azad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151050/adam-azad)'s answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137394/), I started working on creating a multi-language web app that saves a user's selected language. I can successfully switch back and forth between English and Korean for all contents in my web app except for contents in `swal` messages in `SweetAlert2`.

 - After setting up, I added `class="lang"` and `key="(a key name that matches a content goes here)"` for each content that I would like to translate back and forth.

Because I was able to customized `confirmButtonText` by changing from `Got it!` to `'<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Got it!</div>'`, I thought I could simply add `class="lang"` and a key name **to create multi-language popup messages in SweetAlert2.**

 - Changed from `'Thank you!'` to `'<h2 class="lang" key="thxMsgTitle"></h2>'` : nothing shows up.
 - Changed form `'Your input has been recorded.'` to `'<div class="lang" key="thxMsgContent"></div>'` : instead of the text, the code shows up in the popup message.
 - Changed from `<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Got it!</div>` to `'<div class="lang" key="thxMsgConfirmBtnTxt" id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000"></div>'` : nothing shows up.

**Also,**
I tried `if(lang == 'en-us')` and `else if(lang == 'ko')`.
 It worked great on page load. **But,** when I clicked a different "language" button, the language in `SweetAlert2` messages were not changed,  while contents not in `SweetAlert2` messages were changed to a different language.

**What I would like to achieve:**
 - Change all contents to English when the "English" button is clicked including contents in `SweetAlert2` messages
 - Change all contents to Korean when the "Korean" button is clicked including contents in `SweetAlert2` messages

I was going to include my code in this post via code snippet. But, it gave me an error message and my code did not work.
So, **please look at this JSfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/hlim188/15no3zyd/69/.
(I put non-working codes as comments.)

I'd greatly appreciate any insight on solving this issue. Thanks in advance! :-)

**Explanation of "[vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)":**
Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.
 - *I took a lot of efforts before & while posting this question...*
 - *Instead of voting down, please give me any advice of solving this problem...*

The [up-vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Comment: Why downvote...? Please give me an explanation... If you think it's a duplicate, please tell me why. I'd love to solve this problem and couldn't find an answer even after reading several posts in StackOverflow.

Comment: You need to pass message in sweet alert according to the language selected.

Comment: @Riddhi Because I was able to customized confirmButtonText by changing from "Got it!" to "<div id="swal2-confirmBtnTxt" style="color:#000000">Got it!</div>", I am wondering if it's possible to create multi-language popup messages in SweetAlert2. I didn't ask this question without trying anything...

Comment: @J L I haven't downvoted anyway!

Comment: @Riddhi oh! thx for letting me know :)

Comment: Why another downvote....?! For those who give downvotes, please give me explanation... I tried my best to give an explanation of my problem. I'd greatly appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do your

```
$(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
```

The SweetAlert elements will not be loaded onto the page yet...
You should either call this again straight after the SweetAlert call, or add some kind of event listener that does this when elements are added dynamically.

Alternatively you could just pull the correct value out of the array as you create your SWAL;

```
confirmButtonText: arrLang[lang]['thxMsgConfirmBtnTxt']
```

Comment: Thank you! Pulling the correct value out of the array as I created your SWAL didn't automatically update contents when "English" or "Korean" buttons was clicked after a webpage was loaded. So, I forced a webpage to refresh when "English" or "Korean" buttons was clicked. It's not a perfect solution. But, it's okay to move on for now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Milney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102132/milney)'s answer in this post  & [Adam Azad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151050/adam-azad)'s answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137394/), I was able to create a multilingual website.

***STEP 1*** : Pulling the correct value out of the array as I created `SweetAlert2` messages.
(e.g., `confirmButtonText: arrLang[lang]['thxMsgConfirmBtnTxt']`)

***STEP 2*** : Because that didn't automatically update contents in `SweetAlert2` messages when "English" or "Korean" button was clicked, I forced a webpage to refresh when "English" or "Korean" button was clicked by adding `value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload()"`.

I wanted to include code by using code snippet. But, an error message showed up, although I copied & pasted code from JSFiddle. Please check a working example here : https://jsfiddle.net/hlim188/15no3zyd/80/.

> If you would like to know detailed information of how I created it, please read this [blog post](https://medium.com/@hyejunglim/how-to-create-customized-multilingual-sweetalert2-messages-ea931bfb168b) :)