# Language switch - use HTML not Key

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I see the excellent forum before on how to use Json to create a multi language site ([Build multiple language website using jQuery and JSON based methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137394/build-multiple-language-website-using-jquery-and-json-based-methods)).

I wanted to see if it is possible to use this, but not using the key attribute, instead have as normal HTML. Please see codepen:- https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/ZEzpOpm

I can see that the key is being called within the jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="translate" id="en-gb">English</button>
<button class="translate" id="zh-tw">Chinese</button>

<ul>
  <li class="lang" key="HOME"></li>
  <li class="lang" key="ABOUT"></li>
  <li class="lang" key="CONTACT"></li>
  <li class="lang">Home</li>
</ul>
```

```js
var arrLang = {
  "en-gb": {
    "HOME": "Home",
    "ABOUT": "About Us",
    "CONTACT": "Contact Us",
  },
  "zh-tw": {
    "HOME": "首頁",
    "ABOUT": "關於我們",
    "CONTACT": "聯絡我們",
  }
};

// The default language is English
var lang = "en-gb";

// Check for localStorage support
if ('localStorage' in window) {
  var usrLang = localStorage.getItem('uiLang');
  if (usrLang) {
    lang = usrLang
  }
}

console.log(lang);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
  });
});

// get/set the selected language
$(".translate").click(function() {
  var lang = $(this).attr("id");

  // update localStorage key
  if ('localStorage' in window) {
    localStorage.setItem('uiLang', lang);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('uiLang'));
  }

  $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
  });
});
```

I have changed this to HTML but still no luck, anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: `I wanted to see if it is possible to use this, but not using the key attribute, instead have as normal HTML` That doesn't make much sense, as the `key` is required to know which language to lookup in the JS object.

Comment: Yes I wondering if this could be changed, so it targets just the HTML within the div, and not the key

Comment: Well you could go off of text, but once it is not english, you would not be able to swap it easily. The key is what simplifies it.

Comment: @epascarello, i misread the question.

Comment: Is using a key best practise for an entire website? Because we will be looking to switch languages for large pages, so I was wondering if there was a way to target the HTML rather than the key. Or would best practise always be to use the key? And then wrap the text needing to be changed within <span> or <div> etc...?

Comment: The thing is with this, it can be simplified. Drop the class and leave the attribute.

Comment: Just a simple remarks if you want to have a really clean code, the HTML5 specifications allow custom attributes, but you need to prefix them with "data-". More info on : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: @Brad, have you considered using the "id" attribute?

Comment: So would there be a way to target all HTML instead of looking for the key? E.g. I want to find every word that says 'Home', not just the word' Home' within the key

Comment: Problem is you would have to change how it would work..... And once you change it once from English to Chinese, you would not have a simple look up since the text would be in Chinese. What you are gaining by not having to set the key is making it more complex.

Comment: @Brad, don't think replacing every "Home" word is a good idea. Imagine a paragraph that contains the word "Home", that word will be translated to "首頁" which will be a bug.

Comment: Sure, so using 'Key' is okay for websites?

Comment: also instead of using key, i suggest you use class attribute, it will simplify your code a little.

Comment: for(var key in arrLang[lang]) {
            $('.'+key).text(arrLang[lang][key]);
          }

Comment: if you feel that there are too many occurrence and it is impacting your page performance, consider using vanilla js over jquery. jquery is notorious for its poor performance

Comment: Hi Mox, could you please provide a code example of changing this to class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify, drop the css class and just use the reference.

```js
var arrLang = {
  "en-gb": {
    "HOME": "Home",
    "ABOUT": "About Us",
    "CONTACT": "Contact Us",
  },
  "zh-tw": {
    "HOME": "首頁",
    "ABOUT": "關於我們",
    "CONTACT": "聯絡我們",
  }
}

function setText (lang) {
  // localStorage.setItem('uiLang', lang);
  $("[data-key]").text( function () {
    var key = $(this).data('key')
    return arrLang[lang][key] || key
  })
}

$(".translate").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setText(this.id)
});

// setText(localStorage.getItem('uiLang') || 'en-gb');
setText('en-gb');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="translate" id="en-gb">English</button>
<button class="translate" id="zh-tw">Chinese</button>

<ul>
  <li data-key="HOME"></li>
  <li data-key="ABOUT"></li>
  <li data-key="CONTACT"></li>
</ul>
```

could you do it with just the text? Yes.... but it is more complex and I would end up still using a data attribute....

Comment: Okay, thank you! Can you input HTML with the data-key? So you can have a href links here?