# Working HTML tags from JavaScript file (JSON jQuery?)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am pulling a text from a JavaScript file but the HTML tags don't work.

I followed the best answer here and ran into that problem: 
[Build multiple language website using jQuery and JSON based methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137394/build-multiple-language-website-using-jquery-and-json-based-methods)

This is the part of the JavaScript file:

```
    var arrLang = {
    "en-gb": {
        "HOME": "Home",
        "ABOUT": "About <br> Us",
        "CONTACT": "Contact Us",
    },
    "zh-tw": {
        "HOME": "首頁",
        "ABOUT": "關於我們",
        "CONTACT": "聯絡我們",
    }
}; 
    
    // The default language is English
    var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') || navigator.language.slice(0, 2);
    if (!Object.keys(arrLang).includes(lang)){
        lang = 'en';
    }
    // Check for localStorage support
    if('localStorage' in window){
       
       var usrLang = localStorage.getItem('uiLang');
       if(usrLang) {
           lang = usrLang;
       }
    
    }
    
    
    console.log(lang);
    
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 "use strict";
              $(".lang").each(function() {
                $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
              });
            });
    
            // get/set the selected language
            $(".language-button").click(function() {
                 "use strict";
              var lang = $(this).attr("id");
              localStorage.setItem('lang', $(this).attr("id"));
              
    
              // update localStorage key
              if('localStorage' in window){
                   localStorage.setItem('uiLang', lang);
                   console.log( localStorage.getItem('uiLang') );
              }
    
              $(".lang").each(function() {
                $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
              });
            });
```

HTML: This is how I pull the Text:

```
<div class="lang" key="ABOUT"></div>
```

HTML: Expected result:

```
About
Us
```

HTML: This is what I get:

```
About <br> Us
```

What is a very simple way to make the HTML tags work in this case?

Comment: Please place inside `<pre></pre>` tag

Comment: How did you pull out  the text from arrLang on page ?

Comment: do it - `$(this).html(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov
Thank you very much, this was the solution! I now have learned that text only transfers the plain text, ignoring the html tags.
Have a very nice day!

Comment: @Blacksite, no problem. Good day to you, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use use `.innerText` in your JavaScript file to put the values into the HTML file, you might want to use `.innerHTML` instead. This will help if you have tags (like the `<br>` tag in your situation) in your values.

> If you use something else to put the values into the HTML file, please clarify which method you use...

You can find more information about `innerHTML` vs `innerText` [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/innertext-vs-innerhtml).

Comment: Thank you, I have added the entire JS code, but it seems as innerHTML is not used anywhere

Comment: Indeed, I saw you already found the solution. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a very nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

you're not specifying how you do the replacement, but given your data

```js
var arrLang = {
  "en": {
    "HOME": "Home",
    "ABOUT": "About <br> Us",
    "CONTACT": "Contact Us",
  },
};
```

you could simply have:

```js
var arrLang = {
  "en": {
    "HOME": "Home",
    "ABOUT": "About <br> Us",
    "CONTACT": "Contact Us",
  },
};

var languageSelected = 'en';
var langData = arrLang[languageSelected];

// for each key in your object
Object.keys(langData).forEach(k => {
  // search for attribute "key" and add string as HTML
  $(`[key=${k}]`).html(langData[k]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><div class="lang" key="HOME"></div></li>
  <li><div class="lang" key="ABOUT"></div></li>
  <li><div class="lang" key="CONTACT"></div></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added the whole JS code.
I am stil trying out your answer to make it work somehow

Comment: Thank you I saw you have also used '.html' which in my case was the solution :)
Have a nice day!